# Joining two selects into 4 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two select statements to form 4 columns in one table. My desired result would be something like this

```
+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| ExpectedDate | ExpectedAmount |    ActualDate    | ActualAmount |
+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| 01/03/2014   |          65161 | 2014-03-01 00:00 | 57           |
| 02/03/2014   |             64 | 2014-03-02 00:00 | 321651651    |
| 03/03/2014   |              8 | 2014-03-03 00:00 | 233258646    |
| 04/03/2014   |            561 | 2014-03-04 00:00 | 2321         |
| 05/03/2014   |         651651 | 2014-03-05 00:00 | 8494561      |
| 06/03/2014   |      651616131 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 07/03/2014   |      316548478 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 08/03/2014   |      646512132 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 10/03/2014   |      654984984 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 11/03/2014   |      323213218 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 12/03/2014   |        6464651 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 13/03/2014   |         313218 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 14/03/2014   |         849898 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 15/03/2014   |        3213218 | NULL             | NULL         |
| 16/03/2014   |        9898465 | NULL             | NULL         |
+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I have the following SQL at the moment, which is very close, but instead of being in the same rows, they are split up like this:

```
+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| ExpectedDate | ExpectedAmount |    ActualDate    | ActualAmount |
+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| 01/03/2014   | 65161          | NULL             | NULL         |
| 02/03/2014   | 64             | NULL             | NULL         |
| 03/03/2014   | 8              | NULL             | NULL         |
| 04/03/2014   | 561            | NULL             | NULL         |
| 05/03/2014   | 651651         | NULL             | NULL         |
| 06/03/2014   | 651616131      | NULL             | NULL         |
| 07/03/2014   | 316548478      | NULL             | NULL         |
| 08/03/2014   | 646512132      | NULL             | NULL         |
| 10/03/2014   | 654984984      | NULL             | NULL         |
| 11/03/2014   | 323213218      | NULL             | NULL         |
| 12/03/2014   | 6464651        | NULL             | NULL         |
| 13/03/2014   | 313218         | NULL             | NULL         |
| 14/03/2014   | 849898         | NULL             | NULL         |
| 15/03/2014   | 3213218        | NULL             | NULL         |
| 16/03/2014   | 9898465        | NULL             | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL           | 2014-03-01 00:00 | 57           |
| NULL         | NULL           | 2014-03-02 00:00 | 321651651    |
| NULL         | NULL           | 2014-03-03 00:00 | 233258646    |
| NULL         | NULL           | 2014-03-04 00:00 | 2321         |
| NULL         | NULL           | 2014-03-05 00:00 | 8494561      |
+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
```

Here is the SQL:

```
--DECLARE PERIOD
DECLARE @NextMonthDate VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @currentMonthDate VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @VarientVar VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @ExpectedDateSample VARCHAR(10)

--SET PERIOD
SET @NextMonthDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MONTH, +1, GETDATE()), 112),5,2)
SET @currentMonthDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()))+'-'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MONTH, +0, GETDATE()), 112),5,2)
SET @ExpectedDateSample = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MONTH, +0, GETDATE()), 112),5,2)+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()))

SELECT e.ExpectedDate, e.ExpectedAmount, a.ActualDate, a.ActualAmount
FROM (SELECT ExpectedDate, SUM(ExpectedPayment) ExpectedAmount
FROM Simplicity..V_PaymentPlan2
WHERE Period >= @currentMonthDate and Period < @NextMonthDate AND HyphenStatus != 'Unpaid' AND ExpectedDate LIKE '%'+@ExpectedDateSample+'%'
GROUP BY ExpectedDate) e
FULL JOIN
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, PaymentDate, 20) ActualDate, SUM(ActualPayment) ActualAmount
FROM Simplicity..V_PaymentPlan2
WHERE Period >= @currentMonthDate and Period < @NextMonthDate AND HyphenStatus != 'Unpaid' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, PaymentDate, 20) LIKE '%'+@currentMonthDate+'%'
GROUP BY PaymentDate) a on a.ActualDate = e.ExpectedDate
ORDER BY e.ExpectedDate, a.ActualDate
```

Any idea how to make them line up in the same rows instead of inserting NULL and pushing them down?

I dont have any Primary Key or Foreign Key.

Comment: Well, how do you *want* them to line up? Which lines should be matched to which other?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ExpectedDate,ExpectedAmount, ActualDate, ActualAmount FROM A a1 
   INNER JOIN A a2
ON a1.ExpectedDate = a2.ActualDate
```

Comment: Hey friend, you are missing comma before *.